# Pinescript Warning After Indicator Update To V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I can use some help with the following warning I get when I execute the code:

```
f_top_fractal(src) =\>
src\[4\] \< src\[2\] and src\[3\] \< src\[2\] and src\[2\] \> src\[1\] and src\[2\] \> src\[0\]

f_bot_fractal(src) =\>
src\[4\] \> src\[2\] and src\[3\] \> src\[2\] and src\[2\] \< src\[1\] and src\[2\] \< src\[0\]

f_fractalize(src) =\>
f_top_fractal(src) ? 1 : f_bot_fractal(src) ? -1 : 0
```

*Warning: The function 'f_bot_fractal' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope*

Thank you!

I tried:

```
f_top_fractal(src) =\>
src\[4\] \< src\[2\] and src\[3\] \< src\[2\] and src\[2\] \> src\[1\] and src\[2\] \> src\[0\]

f_bot_fractal(src) =\>
src\[4\] \> src\[2\] and src\[3\] \> src\[2\] and src\[2\] \< src\[1\] and src\[2\] \< src\[0\]

f_fractalize(src) =\>
f_top_fractal(src) ? 1 : 0 
f_bot_fractal(src) ? -1 : 0
```

Result:
Indicator misbehave

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the history referece operator, you should call those functions without a condition. Then use their results in your check.

```
f_fractalize(src) =>
    t = f_top_fractal(src)
    b = f_bot_fractal(src)
    t ? 1 : b ? -1 : 0
```